# Azure analysis Service deployment

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services

I need to set up the analysis service deployment using VSTS or Powershell.
I can deploy the model using PowerShell but data table refresh with data is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Which cmdlet were you using?

I would recommend using the [Invoke-AsCmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps) PowerShell cmdlet. As the `-query` parameter, simply use the TMSL script for refreshing a table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tmsl/refresh-command-tmsl#request